# The values of picklist 2 are dependent on picklist 1

Tags: picklist, validation, validation-rule

I have two picklists.

**Picklist 1** values:
1, 2, 3, 4

**Picklist 2** values:
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'

The values of **picklist 2** are dependent on **picklist 1**:

- if **picklist 1** value = 1 then **picklist 2** value = 'e', 'f'

  if **picklist 1** value = 2 then **picklist 2** value = 'a', 'b'

  if **picklist 1** value = 3 then **picklist 2** value = 'c', 'd'

  if **picklist 1** value = 4 then **picklist 2** value = 'a'

I tried to create a validation rule for this but it did not work.

Is this possible?

Comment: why you're not achieving this combination in piclist dependencies settings?

Comment: Make picklist 2 dependent on picklist 1 set the settings of making this dependent picklist, I do not recommend to use validation rule when there is simpler way to do that.

Comment: You dont need a validation rule here. If picklist2 is dependent on picklist 1 and you have created correct mapping then the validation will be done automatically by SF platform.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments!

I created field dependency for the picklist and it functioned correctly.

Comment: Good to know it worked for you. A more common way to handle this Stack Exchange interaction would be to add a comment to your post asking the people to help you that they post it as an answer so they can be rewarded for helping you.